# AWS Lambda SAM Deployment Automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, build-automation, aws-sam, build-pipeline

We have an application utilizing **API<==>Lambda (Python)<==>S3**. We wanted to automated the deployment process. We are using SAM for local testing and deployment.

I wanted to know, do I need to run SAM DEPLOY all the time manually? Or is there a better way to do this?

Our current build system include,

1. Azure DevOP's TFS  for source control
2. Team City (on-permise) for build server
3. Seperate AWS account for DEV/TEST and PROD

Comment: There is a better way, https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/serverless-cicd-for-enterprise/

Comment: Thanks will look at it.